# Error $1 of `debut' has no declared type Bison/Yacc

Tags: bison, yacc

I have problem on Yacc/Bison.
This is my code :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%union{
double val;

}

%start debut
%token <val> nombre
%left PLUS

%%
debut :
|  ADDITION {printf('%f \n',$1);}
;

ADDITION : nombre PLUS nombre {$$=$1+$3;}
;
%%

void yyerror(char *s){
    printf("%s \n",s);
}

int main(void){
    return yyparse();
}
```

I get this error type :  `$1 of 'debut' has no declared type`

Answer (score 2):

`$1 of debut` is the first symbol of the `debut` production, ie. the ADDITION symbol. As the ADDITION symbol has no declared type, yacc cannot expand the `$1` placeholder to anything meaningful.

To fix the problem, add `%type <val> ADDITION` to the list of definitions (the part before the first `%%`).